# How to specify an output file for result-document to avoid a URL required error

Tags: saxon-js

Trying to specify result-document as below:

`<xsl:result-document href="{$folderName}Dev.json" method="text">`

In NodeJS, Getting error:

`Writing to ./Dev.json Transformation failure:  Error FORG0001 at dl2tm.xsl#27 writeFile('./Dev.json'): expected URL`

What is the proper way to specify the output file to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the transformation has a known base output URI, by specifying the `-o` option on the command line, or by supplying the `baseOutputURI` option in the `transform()` parameters when invoking the transformation.